# Delay in cell for row at index path

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

In cell for row at index path I am fetching info from core data based on which I update the text on the cell..

**It is not a problem if I have less number of rows but It is not smooth if I have more number of cell (500 rows)**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
     MyRecord *record = [self fetchDataForIndexPath:indexPath.row]; //This is line which makes the table view scrolling un silky 
     cell.infolabel.text = record.name;
}
```

Comment: You should run the app with Instruments and Time Profiler so you can find the exact function that causes the bottleneck.

Comment: What is in the function `fetchDataForIndexPath`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When tying a `UITableView` to a core data fetch request, the tool you want is [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/). It will handle caching for you, which is your problem. You're almost certainly performing fetches when you don't need to. You should only refetch data when the data changes.

---

If you aren't using fetch requests directly, then you would manage this by hand. Create an object in front of the data API that is responsible for keeping track of the current displayable state. This object is often called a "view model." See [Introduction to MVVM](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/mvvm.html) for one good discussion of this pattern. Your view model should cache the latest fetched information so that you don't keep re-fetching it every time you display. When the underlying model changes, that's when to notify the table view controller that certain cells need to update.

A key consideration is that you should avoid calling `reloadData` on large table views like this. `reloadData` instructs the table view to dump all of its own cache and start over. Whenever possible you should use the less-drastic methods like `reloadRowsAtindexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...:`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:...:`, etc. Combined with `beginUpdates`, this is a critical part of good user experience on large table views. See ["Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9) from the Table View Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks...I am using an SDK which internally doing some core data fetch that API is not explored to me...Is any other way to handle this other than NSFetchResultController